# Winforms Combobox and Databinding

Tags: c#, winforms, data-binding

I am databinding a combobox to a DataSet, however I want to insert a single item at the top for "None".

Doing:

```
 combobox.Items.Insert(0,"None");
```

Doesn't work, as the combobox is now expecting a DataRowView, however DataRowView doesn't have a public constructor, so I can't fake it that way.

Any advice? I'm sure this is a well solved problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Insert to the object you are databinding to rather than to the combobox. Good example below.

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/winforms/thread/70785e67-5c27-428f-ac79-e45c8c70c3e8/